# Aggregate by NA value in R

Tags: r

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
x2 <- c("a", "b", "a")
x3 <- as.Date(c(NA, "2016/01/01", NA), "%Y/%m/%d")
df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
```

when I apply aggregate to `df`:

```
aggregate(x1~x2+x3, df, sum)
```

The result looks like this but ignored `NA` values:

```
x2         x3   x1
b   2016/01/01  2
```

So what I need is to aggregate `NA` values and have a result like this:

```
x2         x3   x1
a           NA  4
b   2016/01/01  2
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: @jogo about to say the same, but you'll have to design a custom function?

Comment: I'd just suggest using `data.table` or something else that would allow you to group by `NA` values too. Like `library(data.table); as.data.table(df)[, sum(x1), by = .(x2, x3)]`.

Comment: @jogo, I don't think that would work. I'm pretty sure you'd still have to change the "x3" grouping variable so that it doesn't include `NA` values....

Comment: Indeed `dplyr` library by default also keeps the NA: `df %>% group_by(x2, x3) %>% summarise(sum(x1))`

Comment: Sorry for the confusing, x3 should be  x3 <- c(NA, "2016/01/01", NA)
> as.Date(x3)

Comment: @AHandcartAndMohair You are right! I was on the wrong trip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by adding `NA` as a factor level then performing the aggregation:

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
x2 <- c("a", "b", "a")
x3 <- as.factor(as.Date(c(NA, "2016/01/01", NA), "%Y/%m/%d"))
x3 <- addNA(x3)
df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3)

aggregate(x1~x2+x3, df, sum)
```

> ```
>   x2         x3 x1
> 1  b 2016-01-01  2
> 2  a       <NA>  4
> ```

Comment: This really helps. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hao Happy to help!